# In IE11 blur event not fired while mouse down on div element which has unselectable='on' attribute

Tags: javascript, html, events

In IE11 blur event not fired while mouse down on DIV element which has unselectable='on' attribute. In other browsers blur event is fired while mouse down on this DIV element

Without unselectable attribute blur event fires on mouse down on this DIV.
I need unselectable attribute with blur event while mouse down on this DIV, how to achieve this?

Please find code snippet below

```js
 function blurEvent() {
            alert("event fired");
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hello" onblur="blurEvent()"/>
    <div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#0ff" unselectable="on">
        dasdasdsa
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and Webkit support this feature through the proprietary -moz-user-select and -webkit-user-select properties respectively. Internet Explorer, however supports an 'unselectable' attribute on elements. When set to the value "on", text inside the element cannot be selected.

So basically instead of putting the attribute unselectable to on in the div, this can be easily done with CSS. Make a class (say unselect) and put the user-select option to none and then give the div the same class.

**CSS:**

```
.unselect
{
  -moz-user-select: none; /* For firefox */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* for chrome */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* for IE10+ */
}
```

Then provide the div with this class **'unselect'**

```
<input type="text" id="hello"/>
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#0ff" class='unselect'>
    dasdasdsa
</div>
```

In this way, this will work in Firefox/Chrome/IE10+ browsers. The text inside the div will be unselectable and your onBlur event will also get fired. Here is a [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thvn0crr/5/) for your reference.

Comment: I have already tried this, it is not working when hold SHIFT key and mouse click on DIV element. But in other browsers it is working normally.

Comment: You may disable the 'Shift-Click' event in case of IE 11. Here is the [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thvn0crr/9/) for the same. See if it works for you and let me know.

Comment: I cant disable SHIFT key action , i have to do some operation with this.